index difference is not working in the Pandas
I have the data for 1 year which is time series data hourly basis so few timestamps are missing in between them.The shape of this data is (8188, 3) sample data I have attached below.
I am resampling timestamps according to my data duration which will generate all the timestamps of one year even which were missing in my original data df_hourly = temp_df.resample('h').asfreq() the shape of resampled index is (8764, 1)
Now, I am taking the difference of resampled data and original data new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(original_index) so actual index shape should come as (8764-8188=576,) and then I will replace these 576 missing timestamp with median of total
temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['cell'] == cell]
print(temp_df.head())
temp_df.to_csv('temp_df.csv')
print(temp_df.shape)
# get_missing_duplicates(temp_df)
# fill_missing_duplicates()
print(temp_df.shape)
temp_df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['_time'])
print(temp_df['_time'].dtype)
temp_df.set_index('_time', inplace=True)
original_index = temp_df.index
print(original_index)
print("original_index",original_index.shape)
df_hourly = temp_df.resample('h').asfreq()
print(df_hourly)

# This line is not working as expected
new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(original_index)

print("&&&&&&&&&&&&",original_index)
median_value = df['Total'].median()

# new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(temp_df.index)
print("new_rows",new_rows)

new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(original_index)
this line gives the wrong result basically it should return the difference df_hourly.index and

the shape of temp_df is coming as (8188,)
the shape of df_hourly is coming as (8764,)
the shape of new_rows is also coming as (8764,)

The output of the temp_df.index is
DatetimeIndex(['2023-05-22 02:00:04+00:00', '2023-05-22 03:00:03+00:00',
               '2023-05-22 04:00:03+00:00', '2023-05-22 05:00:03+00:00',
               '2023-05-22 06:00:03+00:00', '2023-05-22 07:00:03+00:00',
               '2023-05-22 08:00:03+00:00', '2023-05-22 09:00:03+00:00',
               '2023-05-22 10:00:03+00:00', '2023-05-22 11:00:03+00:00',
               ...
               '2024-05-20 17:00:03+00:00', '2024-05-20 18:00:04+00:00',
               '2024-05-20 20:00:03+00:00', '2024-05-20 21:00:03+00:00',
               '2024-05-20 22:00:03+00:00', '2024-05-20 23:00:03+00:00',
               '2024-05-21 01:00:03+00:00', '2024-05-21 02:00:03+00:00',
               '2024-05-21 04:00:03+00:00', '2024-05-21 05:00:03+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='_time', length=8188, freq=None) 

The output of the df_hourly.index is:
df_hourly_index RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8764, step=1)
(8764, 3)

Sample data:


Can you provide some small example data (a few rows) where your problem still occurs? Also, to provide only the relevant code (for example, all the calls to plot() in your question are unnecessary) so that people can test it out. Many times, in trying to provide a minimal, reproducible example to StackOverflow, you find and solve the problem yourself.

pandas 2.2.1
Problem with resampling of non-uniform timestamps
The issue is not with the code line you mentioned, but with your data. If you look at your time values, you will see that after a whole hour, a few seconds passed before a recording was made:
'2023-05-22 02:00:04+00:00' - 4 seconds after 2:00 
'2023-05-22 03:00:03+00:00' - 3 seconds after 3:00

Hourly resampling eliminates these sporadic biases. Therefore, you will end up with different indexes that may not overlap at all with the original timestamps. So you may need to round your time before resampling in order to find out missing timestamps, sort of:
temp_df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['_time'], utc=True).dt.round('h')

As an alternative, you could find missing timestamps by counting data in each hour. In your code, it could look like this:
new_rows = df_hourly.index[temp_df.resample('h').size() == 0]

If for some reason we need to keep the original timestamps, then I think that asfreq() may not be the best choice; using first() looks more reasonable. Also, I'd add in this case some negative offset when resampling, just in case if some recordings were made a few seconds before the end of an hour, something like this:
df_hourly = temp_df.resample('h', offset=pd.Timedelta('-5min')).first()

If the reason to find the difference between the resampled timestamps and the original ones is to fill in the blanks, we can use fillna(...) instead.
Code to experiment with
The following sample data was taken from the original post with one change to represent a possible problem (see "a second before ..." in the code and a notion about the offset= parameter of resample):
import pandas as pd

timestamps = [
    '2024-05-20 17:00:03+00:00', 
    '2024-05-20 18:00:04+00:00',
    # missing
    '2024-05-20 20:00:03+00:00', 
    '2024-05-20 20:59:59+00:00',     # a second before 21:00:00
    '2024-05-20 22:00:03+00:00', 
    '2024-05-20 23:00:03+00:00',
    # missing
    '2024-05-21 01:00:03+00:00',
    '2024-05-21 02:00:03+00:00',
    # missing
    '2024-05-21 04:00:03+00:00',
    '2024-05-21 05:00:03+00:00'
]

values = [403, 369, 375, 394, 398, 372, 335, 385, 415, 383]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.to_datetime(timestamps, utc=True), 
    'value': values}
)

Option 1: Keep the the original timestamps (no rounding)
five_min = pd.Timedelta('5min')
grouped_by_hour = df.set_index('time').resample('h', offset=-five_min)

resampled_data = grouped_by_hour.first()
is_new_record = grouped_by_hour.size() == 0

resampled_data.loc[is_new_record, 'value'] = round(df['value'].median())
resampled_data['value'] = resampled_data.astype({'value': int})
resampled_data.index += five_min

print('Resampled_data'.upper(),
      resampled_data,
      '\nNew records'.upper(),
      resampled_data.index[is_new_record],
      sep='\n')

Option 2: Round the timestamps to the nearest hour before resampling
rounded_original_time = df['time'].dt.round('h')
resampled_data = (
    df[['value']]
    .set_index(rounded_original_time)
    .resample('h')
    .asfreq()
)
new_records = resampled_data.index.difference(rounded_original_time)
resampled_data.loc[new_records, 'value'] = round(df['value'].median())

print('Resampled_data'.upper(),
      resampled_data,
      '\nNew records'.upper(),
      new_records,
      sep='\n')


Though I am not fully clear with the problem yet, and as mentioned, some example rows, and also error prints will be helpful.
But I think, we need to use temp_df['Total'].median() instead of df['Total'].median().
Also there seems a lot of redundancy as well.
temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

temp_df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['_time'], utc=True)

# Filtering by cell if needed
cell = 'A'
temp_df = temp_df[temp_df['cell'] == cell]

# Ensuring '_time' is the index and sorted
temp_df.set_index('_time', inplace=True)
temp_df = temp_df.sort_index()

# Saving the original index
original_index = temp_df.index

# Resample the data to get all hourly timestamps
df_hourly = temp_df.resample('H').asfreq()

# Calculate the median value for filling
median_value = temp_df['Total'].median()

# Identify the missing timestamps
new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(original_index)

# Fill in the missing timestamps with the median value
df_hourly.loc[new_rows, 'Total'] = median_value

# Reset the index if needed
df_hourly.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Save the result
df_hourly.to_csv('df_hourly.csv')

print("Original DataFrame shape:", temp_df.shape)
print("Resampled DataFrame shape:", df_hourly.shape)
print("Missing timestamps shape:", new_rows.shape)
print(df_hourly.head(10))

Original DataFrame shape: (16376, 2)
Resampled DataFrame shape: (8190, 3)
Missing timestamps shape: (2,)
                      _time cell  Total
0 2023-05-22 00:00:00+00:00    A    0.0
1 2023-05-22 01:00:00+00:00    A    1.0
2 2023-05-22 02:00:00+00:00    A    2.0
3 2023-05-22 03:00:00+00:00    A    3.0
4 2023-05-22 04:00:00+00:00    A    4.0
5 2023-05-22 05:00:00+00:00    A    5.0
6 2023-05-22 06:00:00+00:00    A    6.0
7 2023-05-22 07:00:00+00:00    A    7.0
8 2023-05-22 08:00:00+00:00    A    8.0
9 2023-05-22 09:00:00+00:00    A    9.0


new_rows = df_hourly.index.difference(original_index) basically this line is not working properly.
